# Powershell replace function strange behavior

Tags: string, powershell

a simple example and i don't know how to get it to work...

```
 function replace($rep, $by){ 
    Process { $_ -replace $rep, $by }
}
```

when I do

```
"test" | replace("test", "foo")
```

the result is

```
test
```

When I do

```
 function replace(){ 
    Process { $_ -replace "test", "foo" }
}

"test" | replace()
```

the result is

```
foo
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in PowerShell follow the same argument rules as cmdlets and native commands, that is, arguments are separated by spaces (and yes, this also means you don't need to quote your arguments, as they are automatically interpreted as strings in that parsing mode):

```
'test' | replace test foo
```

So if you call a PowerShell function or cmdlet with arguments in parentheses you'll get a single argument that is an array within the function. Invocations of *methods* on objects follow other rules (that look roughly like in C#).

To elaborate a little: PowerShell has two different modes in which it parses a line: *expression mode* and *command mode*. In expression mode PowerShell behaves like a REPL. You can type `1+1` and get `2` back, or type `'foo' -replace 'o'` and get `f` back. Command mode is for mimicking a shell's behaviour. That's when you want to run command, e.g. `Get-ChildItem` or `& 'C:\Program Files\Foo\foo.exe' bar blah`. Within parentheses mode determination starts anew which is why `Write-Host (Get-ChildItem)` is different from `Write-Host Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: thanks ! started powershell yesterday and I lack of that kind of basis.

Comment: It may be a bit confusing at first, especially coming from either C-like languages or Unix shells, but the language designers made careful effort so that you can learn a few concepts and reapply them throughout working with PowerShell. A minor hint: `filter` behaves the same as `function` with a `process` block, so you can simplify your code a little to `filter replace ($rep, $by) { $_ -replace $rep, $by }`

Comment: coming from c# is a bit confusing sometimes but powershell seems to be a very powerfull alternative to unreadable vbs scripts or c# compiled application. thx for the filter tip !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the () in your function call and [remove comma](http://www.johndcook.com/powershell_gotchas.html).

```
"test" | replace "test" "foo"
```